# Having a long winter every four years - regularly

Tags: planets, seasons

I'm in the process of writing my novel (actually I've just about finished the second draft and am due to send it to my editor).

It is a fantasy/sci-fi mix, and every four years the planet experiences a much longer and harsher winter. By longer, I mean it lasts for a couple of months longer than our average winter, nothing too crazy. However, it has been bugging me lately that, without going into story detail, I will need a 'scientific' explanation as to why this happens; I don't want to say 'it is just magic'.

Some facts about the planet:

- It is earth-like, similar in mass, size and make-up
- It lies in the habitable zone of it's star, which is of a similar size to our sun
- It has one moon, similar in size to our moon
- Most of the kingdoms on this planet are based in the northern hemisphere

I'm open to changing the above facts, such as quantity of moons or star quantity/classification if it will help with the 'science'.

I am also open to changing the regularity of the long winters. For example, if reducing them to every two years, or increasing them to every eight or sixteen years, I would be able to adapt the story to this. But I want it to be 'regular', I don't want it to be random to the point where it ends up being a carbon copy of GOT.

So I've done some research on axial tilts, eccentric orbits, or perhaps even ocean currents warming to affect seasons. But my scientific knowledge is limited, and I am looking for a basic explanation as to how a planet could have earth-like seasons, with the occasional longer and harsher winter sprinkled in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seasons increasing and decreasing in length in a predictable cycle?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/238614/seasons-increasing-and-decreasing-in-length-in-a-predictable-cycle) If you believe it does not, please [edit] your question to explain why it does not meet your needs (note that the details of your world are usually insufficient reason to reject a duplicate, the basic causes will remain the same).

Comment: Tom Godwin's "Space Prison" has a similar idea over a much longer cycle where the climate varies over a period like 50 years from extremely hot to very very cold.  I don't recall what the source of the variation was.

Comment: I took a look at Space Prison.  In that story the planet is in' orbit around a yellow star that is part of a binary system.  The other star in the system is a blue star, and I think the two stars are in a long term, elongated orbit.  When the stars are close together and the planet passes between them it gets really, really, really hot.

Comment: Partial eclipse might work. It'll block enough sun to create a chill but not too much to create darkness.

Comment: Are you aware that winter happens on the north half of the planet while the south half is having summer, and vice versa?

Comment: This question has superior answers. It is the other question that should have been closed, even though it was asked first.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm thinking it's just not a duplicate. Both questions are very specific, but different setups, and the answers aren't entirely interchangeable.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this closed because this question involves a scenario that is almost identical to one in the referenced duplicated question. The actual question itself is nearly identical as well, to paraphrase: "How can I explain these seasonal changes without magic?"
 There is no clear reason given in this question why the duplicated question does not suffice. This is clearly a duplicate, and any method provided as answer to the one question could answer the other with minor detail changes.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe the star has a four-year cycle just like our Sun has an [eleven-year cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cycle)?

The energy output of our Sun varies by about 0.1% during the cycle, which results in about 0.2 °C or 0.3 °F variation in average tempeatures on Earth, which is quite noticeable. Your star could have a stronger variation. Note that a variation in average temperature of 1 °C or 2 °F would have dramatic effects.

Comment: Note this would also make summers cooler as well as winters longer. As for the degree of the effect, climate is complicated enough that there could easily be positive feedback effects making cold winters colder and warm winters warmer.

Comment: Cycles mean that *every* year would be different, not just one in four.

Comment: @RonJohn: Yes, one of four years will have a short winter, two will have normal-length winters and one will have a long winter. On the average.

Comment: Is that what OP wants?

Comment: @RonJohn: All years are different anyway, aren't they, regardless of what one wants...

Comment: "All years are different anyway".  I had thought of that.  Early frosts, late frosts, mild winters, harsh winters...

Answer (score 17):

> I will need a 'scientific' explanation as to why this happens

This is the Fandom Effect.

**Ignore it with all your strength**, and write your story, just like George Lucas in *Star Wars*, the ST:TOS writers, Frank Herbert, Ursula K LeGuin, etc, etc all ignored the *how* and focused on the *what happens afterwards*.

When you and the characters take it for granted that winter is long every four years, the readers will too.  (EDIT: this just means that readers are willing to suspend belief.)

Comment: And you have George RR Martin where the winters are literally changing every year, from a few months to tens of years. And he never lost time trying to explain why or how.

Comment: Well, it depends on why he wants it. The entire plot could revolve around discovering the cause of the winter, in which case, it needs a real basis to pursue. Generally I do agree that people can spend a lot of time researching things that their characters didn't need to know, though. If Pippin doesn't need to know the Balrog's origin story, then the Balrog doesn't necessarily need one right there in that book.

Answer (score 9):

**Something blocks the sun every 4 years.**

I'm actually not sure if the orbital physics would work for this, but I'm wondering if your world could get eclipsed, big time, every 4 years. Perhaps a large moon? Every 4 years you get a full eclipse, except it lasts a whole week, resulting in a "long night" and a deep chill. Or maybe your planet *is* a moon, with the eclipsing factor being the gas giant it orbits. Or perhaps there is a gas giant on an inner orbit and once every 4 years you get exactly the right overlap for a long eclipse -- even a partial eclipse that cuts light by, say, 20%, would be quite a different winter.

But, tossing orbital mechanics aside, maybe something more local happens. There's a big volcano that has been erupting like clockwork for as long as anyone can remember. Every 4 years it builds up enough and sets off, blasting enough dust into the atmosphere to create a long winter.  (It doesn't need to do this regularly for thousands of years. It just needs to do it regularly for the period of time your story covers.)

Or the farmers have a long standing practice of [controlled burns](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2021/08/black-carbon-environmental-cost-crop-burning/), which they do every 4 years. They *all* do this during the Burning Year, which is every 4 years. Possibly no one has tied the crop burning to the long winter. Maybe they even think that the burn is meant to stop the long winter from being even worse. ("It's long winter year. Time to burn the fields. If'n we don't, it'll be way worse. The heat helps, you know.")

Comment: With a large enough moon, orbiting at a slow enough rate, it could block the sun on a predictable cycle. Synchronize that with the planet's typical wintertime, and it could easily make 1 in 4 winters much harsher.

Comment: You could put an asteroid field on an elliptical orbit that only comes inside the other planet's orbit every four years. You'd probably also get a lot of shooting stars around that time.

Comment: I would upvote the controlled burn part of the answer if posted as a separate answer.  I do not think it works well as part of an answer that is on a completely different base.

Comment: A gas giant in front of a rock planet is not very likely due to how planet formation works. Rocky planets tend to form in the hotter regions close to the star, while gas giants form in the colder parts further away. See [this link](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/faq/43/how-do-planets-form/#:~:text=Scientists%20think%20planets%2C%20including%20the,within%20the%20disk%20to%20collide.) for more information.

Comment: @The_spider: Gas-giants very close to the parent-star have been found (hot-Jupiters, etc.), as have rocky planets further out.  Even if they happen to be less common than some alternative, that wouldn't seem like a problem.

Comment: An "Old Faithful" volcano is an interesting idea; not so much the **every farmer in the entire world** (or even a continent) burning the fields every four years.  That takes way too much coordination.

Comment: @The_spider My understanding is it's the opposite, based on the survey data we have so far. Gas giants form where the bulk of the loose material is, which is close to the star. Smaller planets further away, because there was less material there. Our system seems to be the odd-ball. There's a theory that we had an inner gas giant, but it [got ejected](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2015/11/03/leading-theory-for-how-the-solar-system-formed-just-disproved/?sh=24f943d7dd86) and pulled Jupiter outward. We're the leftovers of the inner solar system!

Answer (score 6):

How I'd do it -- just mention it in passing that *the interplay of oceanic currents is such that you get a four-year cycle* not unlike the [North Atlantic Oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Atlantic_oscillation), or El Nino, or any other such oscillation. Do not give any more detail than that, unless you need them for the plot.

You can get enough material on weather oscillations to concoct a believable setup for *almost* anything in the "cold winter" ballpark, as long as the anomaly is within about 5 °C average. Mind you, this allows *very harsh* winters - even a few degrees of average anomaly are a *huge* matter.

Otherwise, and more than that -- well, things get difficult to justify. You'd be looking more or less at E. E. Smith's planet Ploor. A variable star might do the trick, but that's not too different from saying that you get a periodic cold winter *because magic* (a star cycle has no reason to be tuned to the planetary year, anyway).

You could get something like that with a (not very realistic) double star system, with a large central star Alpha and a faint G or K-class star, Beta, orbiting it with a four-year period and a markedly elliptical orbit. The only planet of this latter star has stabilized in a 4:1 [resonant orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance).

In year 1, Beta is at perialpha, closest to the large star, and in "winter" the planet is between the two stars. The "winter" is actually quite warm, summer is very hot.

Year 2, Beta is at mid-distance (about 2/3rd of the way around Alpha; not 1/4 because the elliptical orbit has Beta close to Alpha only about one third of the time), the planet is between the two stars in autumn, and experiences a warm autumn and a normal winter.

Year 4, Beta is on the opposite side, mid-distance, the planet experiences a warm spring and again a normal winter.

In Year 3, Beta is at apoalpha, and in winter the planet is farthest from both stars. Autumn is cold, winter sets in early and is very cold, while spring is proportionally slow in coming.

[image]

(The only thing is, sun distances and planetary mass *don't* really allow a stable and realistic configuration, and I don't think the 4:1 resonance is really doable -- but superficially [*waves hands quickly*] it looks plausible).

Comment: 4:1 with a hot-Jupiter, maybe?

Comment: Does "planet between the two stars" mean that most of the planet is in daylight (from 1 star or the other) for several months of that year?

Comment: @Ralph yes, that's another difficulty. You might try and imagine that it's Alpha that supplies most of the daylight, and Beta just contributes largely in the infrared. It depends on how much Earth-like you like your planet. For "reasonably Earth-like" I'd go with the oceanic cycle. Otherwise, I think that daily life on the planet would just get a bit weird.

Answer (score 5):

El Niño

Your world has an oceanic/atmospheric cycle similar to El Niño, but it affects the whole planet and makes the winter longer. It could happen reliably every four years, or be variable in duration and intensity.

Comment: I think this is the simplest and most elegant explanation. It could *not* affect the whole planet, just the area of interest; after all, there's no rule that a story has to involve somehow every spot of the old dirtball. Locals might not even be aware of there *being* a "rest of the planet". They get a devilish winter every four years, and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

You can go probably go an explain it with the planet orbiting a variable star, which every 4 revolutions of the planet happens to have a minimum in the energy emission, resulting in a harsher winter on the planet as a consequence.

Sort of a faster cycle of what the Sun does with Earth.

Comment: The star's would have to *precisely* vary, and happen just when *that* planet's northern (or southern) hemisphere points away from the sun.  And the other three years would also show variability.

Comment: If one wishes to be realistic, nothing is every extremely precise. It may so happen that the variability of the star is 4.1 years, so every 50 years you get something non-standard. It wouldn't be a big deal, and would just add to the realism.

Answer (score 4):

**Precession**

On Earth, the seasons are caused by the planet's tilt. When a country is tilted away from the sun, you get Winter. When the Earth moves to the opposite side of the planet, the tilt is the other way and you have Summer.

[image]

Canadian Summer happens on the left of the image and Canadian Winter on the right.

This assumes the Earth always tilts the same way. In fact the tilt changes very slowly. This is called precession.

[image]

Your planet precesses quickly. It completes three revolutions every four years. The precession is opposite to the orbit, i.e the planet is almost tidally locked.

(**Edit:** This is wrong. Tidal locking means something else. I mean the tilt of the planet is almost "tidally locked" where fully locked would mean the planet always tilts towards the sun.)

One precession per year would mean the same side of the planet is always tilted towards the sun. But 3/4 precessions per year just makes the Summer/Winter cycle take 4 times as long. That means there is a 1-year long period ever four years where Canada points away from the Sun.

Comment: Wouldn't this make all the winters long, not just one out of 4?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Yep.

Comment: Also, being almost tidally locked would mean well over 90% of the planet is uninhabitable at any given time, correct? Any civilization would have to be either deep underground or in constant movement to stay within the band with habitable weather conditions (and only loosely "habitable"; the winds at the border between night and day would be ferociously strong). Life would almost certainly not have evolved here.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it was badly phrased. What I mean was the tilt of the planet is "tidally locked" in that it changes almost in sync with the orbit.

Comment: This just puts the season cycle in "slow motion" - it's the exact same seasonal variation as before, it just takes longer than one orbit to go through it. Every season is 4x as long and changes the exact same way every cycle. You don't really need such a precise and unusual configuration of precession and spin, you can achieve the same thing just by defining the planet to have a longer year.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably read the Helliconia trilogy by Brain Aldiss.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helliconia

The way to achieve roughly what you want is to locate your planet in a binary star system. If the planet orbits one star (A) and that star orbits a second larger star (B) at considerable distance in an elliptical orbit then it should work.

The planet would orbit Star A as Earth orbits the Sun with its axial tilt producing the seasons and with star B at some distance away. Over a much longer time frame of many years star B would get much closer and have a warming effect on the planet while it was in the proximity of star B. The planet would then move further away from star B and its seasons would become much cooler again.

Adjust the luminosity of each star and the orbital parameters like average distance and eccentricity to produce the desired climatic mix. But do not let Star A or the planet get too close to star B (they shouldn't be anywhere near the hill radius of star B).